# Connection Time out, how to manage number of users

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008, connection-pooling

I have two applications asp.net web and C# windows form.

Both applications use same SQL Server 2008 Database.

Windows form application being a parent application is installed by 10-15 users under same network. Heavy load on SQL Server occurs at specific time by Windows form application (Insertion, Update, Deletion), transactions are created.

When heavy load occurs on DB, at times user are not able to login through web application. 
I get **Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.** Even though connection pooling is added in web-application.

Also at time some user are not able to login using Windows Form application.

Please let me know how I should handle this situation.

Comment: Table locks may cause this issue. Open SqlServerManagementTools (SSMS), right click your server and choose `ActivityMonitor`

Comment: Where do the heavy loads come from? A general advice would be to try to move these busy periods to points of time when there are not many users in the application. But that may not be possible if the users themselves cause these peaks.

Comment: Performing bulk updates or delete might promote row locks table locks. Which means no one else can access these rows. Also we encountered a situation where we set the auto growth size of our data file to be very small so any of our sql statement would cause the database to grow the datafile which basically lock the whole database during it resize